# Use toastr with angular2

Tags: angular, toastr

I'm using this node package [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-toastr)

Following the instructions the typescript compiler gets out of mind.
I think the problem is the same described [here](https://github.com/PointInside/ng2-toastr/issues/5) but I cant find a workaround.

Any help?

Thanks a lot

Comment: can i show you withoute node , in plunker?

Comment: An alternative would also be to use a native Angular2 toaster port, such as  https://github.com/Stabzs/Angular2-Toaster

Comment: I'm currently using this one that @DavidL mentioned, it works like a charm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means that you can use directly the `toastr` object directly without having to import it like this: `import * as toastr from '...';`.

That said to avoid compilation error, you need to include the corresponding typings:

```
/// <reference path="./toaster.d.ts" />
```

Here is the way to use Toastr in a component:

```
/// <reference path="./toaster.d.ts" />

import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app', 
  template: `
    <div (click)="displayToastr()">Display Toastr</div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
    toastr.options = { positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right' };
  }

  displayToastr() {
    toastr.info('message');
  }
}
```

Here is the corresponding plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/wzdoisKBrZYTeSX8r7Nd?p=preview.

Comment: Thanks, but in this way how can I configure the options?
I tryied in my root component using **toastr.options = { positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right', }** but with no luck.
EDIT: if I set the options before showing it, this works. But I want to set the options is a global way. Thanks a lot

Comment: Thank you, just another question:
I cant find toastr in DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped. I only found the 'ng-version'. Do you know why? I would also download it with bower (I cant use cdn), is this possible?

Comment: Are you sure? See https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/toastr/toastr.d.ts. Yes you can get toaster lib from bower and include it in your HTML page from the `bower_components` folder...

Comment: Thanks again. GitHub has truncated the file list, this was the reason of the miss

Comment: @ThierryTemplier, is there a way to remove the alert message when we navigate away from the screen?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a Toaster Service under any folder inside your
   application(preferably common) and add the below code in it

   ```
   import { OpaqueToken } from '@angular/core'
   export let Toaster_Token = new OpaqueToken('toastr');
   ```
2. Import this in your App module as below

   ```
   import { Toaster_Token } from './ToasterService';
   ```
3. Declare a variable which has the refrence of window.toastr of the toastr.js as

   ```
   declare let toastr : any;
   ```
4. Add the below code into providers array

   ```
   { provide : Toaster_Token , useValue : toastr }
   ```
5. In your component, import the ToasterService and Inject from angular/core as below

   ```
   import { Toaster_Token } from './ToasterService';
   import { Inject} from '@angular/core';
   ```
6. Your constructor is injected with this service as

   ```
   constructor(@Inject( Toaster_Token ) private _toasterService : any){

   }
   ```
7. Use the toaster methods as

   ```
   this._toasterService.success('This works');
   ```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/D6LY55XHPuaJHGZgIhoG?p=info)**

Comment: not completely understand doing 7 steps instead of 2: declare let toastr and then inject ToastrService to component. Please explain

Comment: Which version you are using?

Comment: Angular 5 . "@angular/core": "^5.2.9"

Comment: Opaque token is removed from angular 4

Answer (score 1):

if you use angular2-toaster  (npm install angular2-toaster)

### in html

`<button class='btn btn-bar btn-warn' (click)='testToaster()'>testToaster</button>`

### in component.js

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
import { ToasterModule, ToasterService, BodyOutputType } from "angular2-toaster";

@NgModule({
    imports: [ BrowserAnimationsModule, ToasterModule],
})

export class Democlass extends BaseComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(...,
    private toasterService: ToasterService) {
. . .}

    public testToaster() {
    this.toasterService.pop("info", "Args Title info", "Args Body <p/>  sdf")
       .bodyOutputType = BodyOutputType.TrustedHtml;
}
```

you can also use other toast properties as

```
   let toast = this.toasterService.pop("info", "demo Title info", "demo Body <p/>  sdf");
   toast.bodyOutputType = BodyOutputType.TrustedHtml;        
   // these will be used
   toast.title = "Actual tite";
   toast.body = "new html body <i>italic</i><hr/>notes";
   // toast.clickHandler = ...
   // toast.type = "error";
   // toast.timeout = 20;
   // ...
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need to add `<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.min.js"></script>`

[toastr - plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VEMcA3SnYtQ35GzVgt80?p=preview)

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app', 
    template: `
      <button (click)="displayToastr()">Display Toastr</button>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
  displayToastr() {
    toastr.info('I am here for few seconds');
  }
}
```

Comment: if it helps you else fine.