# Angular 2 Error: Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges Error: Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges at ViewDestroyedError

Tags: angular

I'm using ng2-toastr and getting the below error

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-toastr

```
Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges Error: Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges at ViewDestroyedError
```

I have this in a button click event.

Comment: Are you doing some actions in an `ngOnDestroy()`?

Comment: No , nothing.I didnot have any ngOnDestroy method

Comment: I am having the exact same error, also on a click event. My problem was that I display a material design snackbar, and when the button is clicked in rapid succession, the error is thrown. This is supposedly fixed in a newer version of material: https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/2392. This is quite specific though, and you are probably having a different problem. I'd try to strip away some actions in your click event function and narrow it down to what specifically causes the error to occur..

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36042125/use-toastr-with-angular2/42239840#42239840

Comment: You can find answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42386249/angular-2-loading-nested-component-is-destroying-the-existing-scope-of-ng2-toa

Answer (score -3):

add this:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.helper.toastr.dispose();}
```

and change in `node_modules/ng2-toastr/bundle/toast-manager.js`:

```
ToastsManager.prototype.dispose = function () {
    var _this = this;
    if (_this.container) {
        _this.container.destroy();
        _this.container = null;
    }
};
```

Comment: Do not change node_modules directly, as they will be overwritten on the next install.